# How dynamic variables implemented for Node.JS in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, language-design, dynamic-variables

First, i'm a beginner in C/C++, be mercyful.

In Node.JS, all variables are dynamic and we can cast the variable any type. So, Node.JS writed with C++ and in C++ or C there is no dynamic variables. So how dynamic variables implemented?

In JS:

```
var A;
A = 5; //Integer
A = "Hello world!"; //String
A = 2.5; //Float
A = 5 * "Hello world!"; // I do not sure about this one.
```

Comment: Oh, C++11 has dynamically-typed variables; they're just not sanitized for you by the compiler or the standard run-time. You can try creating one using `union` paired with RTTI flags (ex: `std::type_info`). Note that in C++17, there will be a standardized `std::any` which is an object which can safely be any type.

Comment: Take a look at [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) and [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). Not exactly the same, but similar. They may not be implemented in every system yet, as they are to be part of C++17.

Comment: I think this question is too broad. Maybe you could make it better by focusing on some aspect of dynamic variables or on some specific piece of JS code?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that V8, the JavaScript engine used by Node.JS is written in C++, but that does not mean JS code gets translated into C++.

Comment: The way dynamic typing is usually implemented (I think this is what you are asking...), then if we have e.g. two types (`struct my_int` and `struct my_string`), then these two share a common structure header. This space is occupied for all types and contains type information. There are some guarantees about the preservation of this header when casting...

Comment: Maybe something like this: struct Type{ char *Type; unsigned int Address;};

Comment: And a class for reading Type and creating a pointer to Address.

Comment: FWIW: while it may be convenient to use these types (or not, they are not nearly as easy to use as in dynamic languages), it would make much more sense to learn how to use the primitive types and use C++ the C++ way.

Comment: I'm researching this because i'm trying to write a interpreted programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two good approaches to this.

The first is to treat local variables as being a name for a succession of values.  This allows you work with the *values*, not the variables, and values have types even if variables do not.

A less efficient way to deal with it is to create polymorphic storage, like `boost::any` or `std::any`.  In the case of JS, there are only a few base types, so `boost::variant` or `std::variant` is more than enough.  (Complex JS objects are just drossed-up key-value maps).

A `variant` is a type of tagged union.  The data structure has an integer or enum that states what type the storage is in, and then a block of storage that can be treated as any of those types.  Accessors check the type, then interact with the data as if it was that type.

The tagged union can replace the stored data with data of a different type by manually destroying it (using `.~X()` syntax), then manually creating a new type at that location (using placement-`new` syntax).  Doing this in C is basically the same with a bit less language support.

The first technique -- figuring out what type is really there and work with it -- tends to be an order of magnitude faster (in the cases where I've seen it profiled), so smart scripting engines work really hard to make that happen.  But the second is functional enough.

Now, I don't know if `node.js` is actually recompiled to C/C++ code.  But after the layers of compiling and parsing and bytecode, it will be interpreted by a C/C++ or assembly interpreter, or it will be compiled itself down to machine code without going through a C/C++ intermediate step.  The solution to this problem in machine code is equivalent to the C/C++ one in any case.